# How do I return the array values despite being inside a nested for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, return-value

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < args.length; counter++){
        System.out.println("Displaying per words: " + args[counter]);
        splitWords = args[counter].toCharArray();
        for(int counter2 = 0; counter2 < splitWords.length; counter2++){
            System.out.println("Word spliced: " + splitWords[counter2]);
            System.out.println("The number equivalent of " + splitWords[counter2] + " is "
                    + (int) splitWords[counter2]);
            occurenceCount[(int)splitWords[counter2]]++;
            System.out.println("The letter " + splitWords[counter2] + 
                    " was shown " + occurenceCount[(int)splitWords[counter2]] + " times.");


        }
    }
```

My function doesn't detect `counter2` as a variable since it was inside the nested for loop. So how do I get out of this dilemma?

I'm trying to use the argument inputs (string respectively) and post the number of occurrences using an ascii table as reference and, as you see, there's just one obstacle from stopping me from accomplishing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't detect"? Where is the problem?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I need to return the number of occurences as array values through int[] occurenceCount. Basically, I want to 'pass' the array values to another function.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that you have missed one important fact - your counts are not complete until after your loop has completed.

You therefore need to print out your counts in a separate loop after your first loop is complete.

```
public void test() {
    String[] args = {"Hello"};
    int[] occurenceCount = new int[256];
    for (int word = 0; word < args.length; word++) {
        System.out.println("Displaying per words: " + args[word]);
        char[] splitWords = args[word].toCharArray();
        for (int character = 0; character < splitWords.length; character++) {
            System.out.println("Word spliced: " + splitWords[character]);
            System.out.println("The number equivalent of " + splitWords[character] + " is "
                    + (int) splitWords[character]);
            occurenceCount[(int) splitWords[character]]++;
            System.out.println("Word spliced: " + splitWords[character]);
        }
    }
    // Scond loop to print the results.
    for (int character = 0; character < occurenceCount.length; character++) {
        int count = occurenceCount[character];
        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.println("The letter " + ((char) character)
                    + " was shown " + count + " times.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense now. I'll just keep revising until my hour streak is over.xD